# Passing form entries to query a database passed and updated to a div tag using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a page with an AJAX style form. Where on submit, the values in the form search and query a database and output the search results into the same DIV as the form was.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ? What specific problem do you have ? Can you show us a short portion of your code that reproduces that problem ? *(basically: many people here will most likely be happy to help, but we won't just write all the code for you)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is probably what you're looking for...

The docs are straightforward. http://jquery.com/

Generally, jQuery follows the find something then do something approach.

- Find something ---> watch for some action on some element (in your
  case, clicking submit)
- Do something ---> make an ajax call to the php page you want to run
  the query and return the results then insert the results where you
  want on the page

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Some other helpful jQuery commands for this task could be...

- http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/
- http://api.jquery.com/remove/
- http://api.jquery.com/append/

Hope this helps.